# Set alpha of a portion of a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view

I need to make a rectangular portion of my view blacked out when the user taps the SearchBar. I cant figure out a way to do that. I tried CGRectMake but how do i set alpha of that rect??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you add another `UIView` and add it on the `UIView` at some event?

Comment: i have a searchbar, when user taps it, i move it upwards using CATransition, and show the cancel button. Now after this i want the rest of the view below the search bar blackish..sort of like the twitter app..#Discover tab

Answer (score 1):

Add an UIImageView with a black background:

```
    UIImageView *myView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    [myView release];
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by adding sublayers to the layer of your view in the following way

UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)] autorelease];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view];

```
CALayer *layerUP = [CALayer layer];
[layerUP setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 50.0)];
[layerUP setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
[view.layer addSublayer:layerUP];

CALayer *layerDown = [CALayer layer];
[layerDown setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, 100.0, 50.0)];
[layerDown setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.2].CGColor];
[view.layer addSublayer:layerDown];
```